# Flow of dereferencing and referencing pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am making my second read trough CPP institute CLA course materials and I am still struggling with pointers. Here is the code snippet that I am trying to understand. I commented my logic in the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
//      we are dereferencing pointer t of type float
//      to = integer literal 1 + float pointer to memory location size 
//      of 2xfloats.
//      I am guessing that this memory location will be filled with 
//      all zeroes or this assignment is invalid.
//      This initial assignment is completely confusing me
//      and rest of my logic/reading this snippet is probably wrong :D

float *t = 1 + (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeof(float));
printf("%f\n",*t);      //0.00000

t--;                    //we move  pointer to next zero in memory?!
printf("%f\n",*t);      //0.00000

*t = 8.0;               //we dereference pointer t and assign literal 
                        //8.0. This will be [0] position
printf("%f\n",*t);      //8.00000

t[1] = *t / 4.0;        //we assign index position [1] to (*t (which 
                        //is previously assigned to 8.0) divided by 
                        //4.0 . This will assign t[1] to 2)
printf("%f\n",*t);      //2.00000

t++;                    //we move pointer to next position [1] = 2
printf("%f\n",*t);      //2.00000

t[-1] = *t / 2.0;       //moving to position [0] and assigning it to 1
printf("%f\n",*t);      //2.00000
free(--t);
return 0;
}
```

Apologies I didn't mention that this is not part of a working program. It is a long list of short "trick" snippets to check understanding of the material. I will go through detailed answers you provided. And Thank you all :D

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Your code comment "I am guessing that this memory location will be filled with all zeroes" is incorrect - don't guess, read the `malloc` man page!

Comment: Remember that pointer arithmetic considers the type. When you add 1 to a pointer, it is increased by the size of its type, in this case by `sizeof(float)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<gratuitous rant>

If this example is representative of the overall quality of the course materials available from the CPP Institute, then I **very strongly** suggest you look elsewhere for your education and/or certification.

Unless this example is titled "How To *NOT* Write Code That Uses Pointers" (in which case it is *very* effective), this code is *awful*.  Not only is it confusing, it's chock full of bad practice and undefined behavior.

</gratuitous rant>

Let's start with the obvious problems:

```
float *t = 1 + (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeof(float));
```

This - I don't know what this is supposed to illustrate, except how to write *really confusing* code.

`sizeof (float)` evaluates to the number of bytes in a `float`, which on most modern platforms will be 4 bytes.  Squaring that value means that you're setting aside enough space for `N` objects where each object is `N` bytes wide - IOW, if `sizeof (float)` is 4, you get enough space for 4 objects, whereas if `sizeof (float)` is 8, you get enough space for 8 objects.

That's an ... *unusual* way of specifying how many objects you want.  Us boring people in the real world just write `sizeof (float) * N`, where `N` is the number of objects we want (actually, we write `sizeof *t * N`).

Okay, so we allocate enough space for N objects and return the pointer - plus 1?  Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the pointed-to type into account, so adding 1 to a pointer means "point to the *next object* of the pointed-to type" (the array subscript operator `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, compute the address of the `i`'th *object* following `a` and dereference the result).

So basically, `t` starts out pointing to the *second* object in the dynamic buffer.  Drawing it out, you get something like this:

```
      +---+
      |   |
      +---+
t ->  |   |
      +---+
      |   |
      +---+
      |   |
      +---+
```

`malloc` does not initialize the dynamic buffer - the contents of the buffer are *indeterminate*.  There's no guarantee that the bit pattern resident in that memory area corresponds to a value of `0.00`.  Since the object is uninitialized, attempting to access its value results in *undefined behavior* - the line

```
printf("%f\n", *t);
```

*may* result in output of `0.0000`, or it may result in some other random value, or you may get a runtime error, or...

The statement

```
t--;
```

subtracts 1 from the pointer, causing it to point to the *first* element in the buffer:

```
      +---+
t ->  |   |
      +---+
      |   |
      +---+
      |   |
      +---+
      |   |
      +---+

*t = 8.0;               //we dereference pointer t and assign literal 
                        //8.0. This will be [0] position
printf("%f\n",*t);      //8.00000
```

Correct, although it would be a bit clearer to write

```
t[0] = 8.0;
printf("%f\n", t[0]);
```

When dealing with something you're treating as an array, it's best to use array subscript notation.

```
t[1] = *t / 4.0;
```

This code *hurts*.  Seriously, mixing array and pointer notation is guaranteed to cause heartburn.  This would better have been written

```
t[1] = t[0] / 4.0;
```

The statement

```
t++;
```

adds 1 to the pointer, getting us back to the previous state where we're pointing at the second element of the array.

```
t[-1] = *t / 2.0;
```

And this code merits a paddlin'.  Negative indices are bad juju.  Since `t` is pointing to the second element of the array now, this won't blow up, but it's just ... just ... *don't do that*.  If anyone turned code like that into me for review, I'd kick it back so hard they'd feel it for a week.  Seriously, **don't do that**.

Here's how that code *should* have been written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 2 // assuming you only want 2 floats.

int main(void) {
  /**
   * Since the type of t is float *, the *expression* *t has
   * type float - thus, sizeof *t == sizeof (float).  Oh, and
   * the cast on malloc is unnecessary, and under C89 will suppress
   * a useful diagnostic if you forget to include stdlib.h.  
   */
  float *t = malloc( sizeof *t * N ); 

  if ( t ) // ***ALWAYS*** check the result of malloc, calloc, or realloc
  {
    t[0] = 8.0; 
    printf( "%f\n", t[0] );      // 8.000

    t[1] = t[0] / 4.0;
    printf( "%f\n", t[1] );      //2.00000

    t[0] = t[1] / 2.0;         
    printf( "%f\n", t[0]);

    free(t);                     // release the memory
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that you can use `calloc` instead of `realloc` if you want the allocated memory to be initialized to all-bits-0:

```
float *t = calloc( N, sizeof *t );
```

Just be aware that all-bits-0 doesn't necessarily correspond to `0.000`.

Comment: Thank you. My eyes bugged out at `sizeof(float) * sizeof(float)`. Wouldn't it be fun if `sizeof(float)` were `1`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman: The `1 +` on that line was what got me - damn near choked on my coffee when I saw that and understood what they were doing.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation this helped and cleared my bad understanding of what allocating memory does. And once more to mention that this "trick" snippet is from a long list of snippets that is testing your understanding of the material. All of them are super weird and make me cry. But I will remember what NOT to do in real world :D

Comment: @Peja: Yeah, I just *hate* these kinds of examples.  There are ways of testing your knowledge without resorting to "tricky" code that has no relationship to real-world code.  Not there isn't some *god awful* real-world code out there, it's just awful in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all your assumptions seem to be correct;
Only the first one "I am guessing that this memory location will be filled with all zeroes or this assignment is invalid" could be a little bit more concrete:

```
float *t = 1 + (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeof(float));
```

allocates memory for several float values; actually `sizeof(float) * sizeof(float)` rarely makes sense as the number of float values available depends on the size of a float. It does not initialize the memory with 0, such that the memory is not initialized. And - that's the main thing now - accessing uninitialized values as you do with `printf("%f\n",*t);` yields undefined behaviour. The compiler is allowed to do anything, even completely ignore the statement.

So you'd actually write

```
float *t = 1 + (float *) calloc(sizeof(float), 4);
```

`calloc` initializes the memory to `0`, and the number of floats is a bit more deterministic.

Comment: Theoretically the `calloc` is insufficient as the system might not be following IEC 60559

Answer (score 0):

The first `printf("%f\n",*t);` causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) by reading an uninitialized memory location and passing the result to a standard library function.

As explained in the link, this means the entire output of the program is meaningless. There is no point even reading the code beyond this line.